# Transfer only certain columns in excel 2007 to another sheet

Tags: worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2007

I have an excel 2007 sheet I am using as my product database. It has various columns and rows with data as below:

```
Code    Company  Image Code   Picture Page
UV001   UV Gear  uv001.jpg    http://www.uvgear.co.uk/product/images/fs_uv001.jpg
```

I want to  export certain columns and certain rows to a csv file for uploading to google adwords.

The problem I have is that I do not want all the rows or all the columns to export. I have 450 product rows but only want to export approx 250 active/In stock lines. I guess I need some sort of True or False rule at the head of each row and column?

Please treat me as a complete excel novice!, thank you
Nick

Comment: What is the criteria of selection?

Comment: Thanks jcbermu Sorry do you mean which columns are required? if so they vary as to what is in stock at the time of the upload. I dont want to waste money loading old pages or non stock items.

Comment: I do have a 'stock' column so could label as 'In stock' or 'old' if that helps differentiate

Answer (score 0):

Since you have an `stock` column then based on the values on that column you can  filter to see only the desired rows:

1. On the *Data tab*, click on *Filter*.

[image]

2. Now you have little triangles on top of each column, you can click on any of them to filter rows of the worksheet using as criteria the values of that column.
3. When you have visible only the information you want then go to *Home Tab* and click on *Find & Select*. In the menu select the option *Go To Special*
   [image]
4. Now in the multiple choice dialog select *"Visible Cells Only"*.
   [image]
5. Only the visible cells are selected, so you can *copy* and *paste* them on another worksheet that you can save as *csv*.

Comment: Tada! perfect and easy when you know how ha ha.

Comment: Sorry one more question! Thats great for achieving the rows but is they also a way of only exporting select certain columns via a similar method. thanks again!

Comment: The only way I know is, **before step 3**, right-click on the *non-desired* column and select `Hide`. Do that for each non-desired column and then continue with step 3.